# Sub query returning multiple results within an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below SQL which is trying to insert into the financial_history_details table using sub queries as I need the statement to pull data from other parts of the table.

This is ok if there is one line of information. My issue is that I am trying to insert thousands of lines of data, with certain bits of information (`batch_number, contact_number`) pulled from different tables.

I thought about using a subquery as seen in this statement, but as I've already said it doesn't work amazingly well as it only inserts one piece of data at a time.

```
INSERT INTO financial_history (batch_number, transaction_number, contact_number, transaction_date, 
            transaction_type, amount, payment_method, posted, address_number, currency_amount) 
VALUES ((select batch_number from event_bookings where batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches)), 1,
(select contact_number from event_bookings where batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches)),
'20-sep-2017', 'P', 0, 'CASH', '20-sep-2017', 
(select address_number from event_bookings where batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches)), 0) ;
```

I have also tried using import from CSV but this is causing a number of problems which make it an impractical solution:

```
BULK
INSERT batches
FROM 'C:\batches.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want an `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into financial_history (batch_number, transaction_number, contact_number, transaction_date, 
            transaction_type, amount, payment_method, posted, address_number, currency_amount) 
    select . . .
    from event_bookings
    where batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches);
```

It is unclear what values you want for the columns, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, using a single SELECT and avoid repeating multiple accesses to the same table (you can also use SELECT without insert to check output)

```
INSERT INTO financial_history (batch_number, transaction_number, contact_number, transaction_date, 
            transaction_type, amount, payment_method, posted, address_number, currency_amount) 
SELECT batch_number, 1, contact_number, '20-sep-2017', 'P', 0, 'CASH', '20-sep-2017', address_number from event_bookings
WHERE batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches);
```

Hints:

- use CONVERT for dates and do not rely on implicit conversion (supposing your destination columns are datetime datatype: eg. *CONVERT(datetime,'20/09/2017', 103) 106)*   )

A more readable form of the same query:

```
INSERT INTO financial_history (batch_number, transaction_number, contact_number, transaction_date, 
            transaction_type, amount, payment_method, posted, address_number, currency_amount) 
SELECT batch_number
  , 1 AS TRANSACTION_NUMBER
  , contact_number
  , '20-sep-2017' AS TRANSACTION_DATE
  , 'P' AS TRANSACTION TYPE
  , 0 AS AMOUNT
  , 'CASH' AS PAYMENT_METHOD
  , '20-sep-2017' AS POSTED
  , address_number 
  FROM event_bookings
  WHERE batch_number not in (select batch_number from batches);
```